# Need help creating complex loop around existing script

Tags: python, pandas, image, loops, image-processing

I have a script used to draw rectangles over multiple features within an image, based upon the pre-extracted x/y/r pixel coordinates of said features.
This script is as follows:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
import glob
import re                       # import RegEx module

xeno_data = 'C:\file_path\data.xlsx'
ss = pd.read_excel(xeno_data)
```

These three pixel coord values (x/y/r) are all contained within the same column in the Excel spreadsheet, hence the following step to seperate them into seperate numbers:

```
    # Extract filenames and coordinates from Excel spreadsheet (data.xlsx):
FandC = []
for index, row in ss.iterrows():
   filename = row['filename']
   coords   = row['xyr_coords']
       # Use RegEx to find anything that looks like a group of digits, possibly seperated by decimal point:
   x, y, r = re.findall(r'[0-9.]+',coords)
   print(f'DEBUG: filename={filename}, x={x}, y={y}, r={r}')
   FandC.append({'filename': filename, 'x':x, 'y':y, 'r':r})
```

Creating new dataframes for the values of interest - 'filename', 'x', 'y', and 'r':

```
fandc=pd.DataFrame(FandC)
    #creates a dataframe for "filename", "x", "y", and "r".

fandc['filename'] [fandc['filename']=='Image1.jpg']
    # shows "fandc['filename']" where the "filename" is equal to (==) the string "Image1.jpg".

fandc_f = fandc[fandc['filename']=='Image1.jpg']
    # create new df called "fandc_f" that only includes "fandc['filename']" where "filename" == "Image1.jpg".

for index , row in fandc_f.iterrows():
    row
    break
```

Draw a transparent rectangle:

```
im = im.convert('RGBA')
overlay = Image.new('RGBA', im.size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(overlay)

for index, row in fandc_f.iterrows():
    for i in range(len(fandc_f)):
        draw.rectangle(((float(row['x'])-float(row['r']), float(row['y'])-float(row['r'])), (float(row['x'])+float(row['r']), float(row['y'])+float(row['r']))), fill=(255,0,0,55))

# Remove alpha for saving in jpg format:        
img = Image.alpha_composite(im, overlay)
img = img.convert("RGB")
```

This code is working perfectly... for one image:

[image: IMAGE_OUTPUT]

However, now I need to wrap the whole process in with a big loop on the outside that automatically goes through each unique filenames in a pandas df.

For each one I need it to: load the image, filter the df for respective filenames, apply my rectangle drawing loop, save the image, and then loop on to next image automatically (as I have thousands of images to process, and cannot do it manually).

If any clarification is needed ask away! :)

Thanks,
Rhod

Comment: I have managed to list the unique filenames in the spreadsheet using: '''list(enumerate(fandc['filename'].unique()))''' But I dont know if this is helpful or heading in the right direction.

Comment: Use `def ProcessOne():` to create a function that processes one image. Call that, with whatever parameters it needs, from inside a loop that iterates over your dataframe.

Comment: I dont quite understand sorry Mark, could you explain further pls? Or link me to a good resource for this as I cant find much online.

Comment: This should help... https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Comment: Trying to implement a function around the part of the script specific to the one image. I have wraped the section of code between `fandc_f = fandc[fandc['filename'] == 'Image1.jpg']` and `img = img.convert("RGB")` above in a _def ProcessOne()_ function. However I'm, getting the following error message when executing ProcessOne(): **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'im' referenced before assignment**

Comment: I'm no expert in Pandas, and writing it all for you is a bit beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer. I can only suggest you read something like this https://thispointer.com/pandas-6-different-ways-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-update-while-iterating-row-by-row/ and everywhere they have a `print()` you call a tiny function called `ProcessOne()` instead and work out how to pass in the parameters and print them in the function and then build on it from there.